# PIVOT in SQL Server with no aggregate function

Tags: sql-server, pivot

I have a table like this (lets call it `T1`):

```
   Date    | Category | Data
-------------------------------
2014-01-01 | 1        | 1.0
2014-01-01 | 2        | 2.0
2014-01-01 | 3        | 3.0
2014-01-02 | 1        | 4.0
2014-01-02 | 2        | 5.0
2014-01-02 | 3        | 6.0
```

Note that `Data` are floating point numbers, not sequential, I just made them that way so it's easier to see where they land up in the result. There is also a table translating the `Category` numbers to names (lets say (`T2`):

```
Category | Name
----------------
1        | A
2        | B
3        | C
```

And I would like a query that could return:

```
   Date    |   B   |   C   
---------------------------
2014-01-01 |  2.0  |  3.0  
2014-01-02 |  5.0  |  6.0
```

I thought about trying with `PIVOT` which I haven't used before, however, I can't find a way to do it without using a aggregation function. But then I though that since I only actually have a single row per `Date` / `Category` combo using an aggregation like `AVG` should work. This is my try based on [these docs](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx):

```
SELECT [Date],
       [2] as B,
       [3] as C
FROM (SELECT * FROM T1 WHERE Category >= 2) AS SourceTable
PIVOT
(
    AVG(Data)
    FOR Category IN ([2], [3])
) AS PivotTable;
```

Which gets kind of close:

```
   Date    |   B   |   C   
---------------------------
2014-01-01 |  2.0  |  NULL  
2014-01-01 |  NULL |  3.0
2014-01-02 |  5.0  |  NULL
2014-01-02 |  NULL |  6.0
```

But how do I get rid of the nulls and get all the same dates to be on the same row?

Comment: This works as expected (two rows in the result), where is your problem?

Comment: You have more columns in your table that you are not showing here. Perhaps an ID identity column that makes each row unique. When you do `select * ` in your subquery you are retrieving the ID column as well and that makes your result into what you see. Change the * to the columns you actually need (date, data and category).

Comment: To emphasize Mikael's point - consider the result set you currently have immediately before you apply the `PIVOT` operator. *every* column that you don't mention inside of the `PIVOT` operator effectively becomes a `GROUP BY` column, and so every unique combination of those (unmentioned in the `PIVOT`) columns will generate a row in the result set.

Comment: @MikaelEriksson Thanks, you are exactly right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only have one value for each result, you can use any of the aggregate functions - eg: `MAX`

```
select * from 
    (select t.date, t.data,c.name from t1 t inner join category c on t.category = c.category) s
pivot (max(data) for name in ([b],[c])) p
```

The first part is the source data

```
select t.date, t.data,c.name from t1 t inner join category c on t.category = c.category
```

Then the `pivot` rearranges it, creating columns for the `in` values from the `name` column, and using the aggregate (`max(data)`) for the value in that column, which should give the desired results.

If you're getting nulls, it's probably from using `select *` in your source query, rather than selecting the required fields - ie: replace

```
SELECT * FROM T1 WHERE Category >= 2
```

with

```
select category, data FROM T1 WHERE Category >= 2
```

Comment: Thanks, please see my updated attempt as I spotted a daft error in my first one.

Comment: Perfect, `SELECT *` was the problem. Thanks!